# Twilio Studio Flow - Adding a Retry/Delay

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio

I'm trying to figure out how I can implement a retry policy in a Twilio Studio Flow. I see that they have an example, but it only has a delay of no more then 10-seconds.

I want something that can use to retry when my webhooks service is down. I did setup the sample from the Twilio docs but it only seems to work when you want a delay of no more then 10-seconds. But I need it to pause for an hour or two. So say the HTTP Post step fails because the webhooks service is offline, I want it to pause for an hour and try again. Then pause for 2, then 3, then 4, etc. and try again. The point being, I don't want to lose the user's response.

What I am trying to do is not lose any of the user responses from a survey if my webhooks application goes down. We saw this happen in production for a couple of hours and we lost survey response from 200 users.

If this is not possible, is there a way I can reach back out to Twilio logs and get access to the responses that failed while the webhooks service was down? I recall running into something where you can pull back the logs, which could then be used to identify the ones that failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of logic isn't really built into Studio. Ten second waits are typically the most you will see due to both Twilio Functions & the `http request` widget timing out at this point.

If you wish to include this kind of wait then you will need some sort of workaround where you go into a send & wait for reply widget (which ignores responses from your customers with some additional logic) and has a timeout set to the amount of time you want to wait. You can then transition to the webhook request again and re-attempt.

Alternatively, you can create a utility which uses the [Execution resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/rest-api/execution) to find all the failed flows for a given time period so you can choose how best to move forward.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I haven't seen where you can use the Execution resource to poll for a given time period, so I will certainly take a look at that. I'm also not familiar with the send & wait widget. I'm using the send response widget to report the answers back to our webhooks apps. If I can use a send & wait widget, that might work... if I could send & wait for say 30 minutes... then call out to a function on a delivery failure. The function would decide if I want to retry or stop. Maybe if it has already retired 10 times, it stops, else it retries.

Comment: Yea that's exactly it. It might require some tricky liquid template logic to calculate your timeouts and to avoid a message disrupting the wait but this is probably the approach. Best of luck!

Comment: Just to follow up on this, you can get all the messages sent to your numbers during your downtime using the [Message resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource).

Comment: @philnash - Much appreciated! I will take a look at pulling in the sent messages as well. Sounds like a good way to id issues, get stats, etc.

Comment: Also, do look into the [fallback URL](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/security/availability-reliability), which Twilio will send webhooks to if your first URL fails. You can set a fallback URL in your number config.

Comment: @Tristan Blackwell: Do you know of a way to configure the send&wait widget without it actually sending a message? If I could do a dummy send&wait and set the timeout for say 30-minutes, that would timeout and execute the send to my webhooks app again. I can track a count for the loop and set it to say 10 tries before stopping. So that would give the webhooks service 5-hours to come back online before I would lose the user reponse. I could extend the timeout or loop count as needed to adjust the delay. The problem is that it looks like I have to send a message to the user to do this.

Comment: @philnash - Hadn't seen the failback URL setting yet. That seems helpful. I'll take a look at that. Thanks for mentioning it